# How Can We Pass a Value From PopUpWindow to Aspx Page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im using the below function:

```
function GetRowValue(val) {
    window.opener.document.getElementById("UniqueKeyField").value = val;
            window.opener.__doPostBack();
                window.close();
        }
```

`window.opener.__doPostBack error` and Even if i have `window.Close()` function Popup window is not closing.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be a Session variable.

```
function GetRowValue(val) {

    var uniqueKey = window.opener.document.getElementById("UniqueKeyField").value;

    //ASP code here for assigning Javascript var to session var
    '<%Session["UniqueKey"] = "' + uniqueKey + '"; %>';
            window.close();
        }
```

Fetch variable with Javascript (if needed)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetUniqueKey()
    {
        var uniqueKey = '<%= Session["UniqueKey"] %>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You SO Much Sir...I got (id)Value from Popupwindow  to aspx page but using that id (which is in textbox) i need to bring details from database.Can you please help me